# How can I use two open and close a popup using two different animations?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm using the animations from the website https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. I have a popup that has an animatoin when it's opened. However I want another animation when the popup is closed. This is what I have so far: 
I add this link that has the animation:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/animate-open.css" />
```

Here is where I call the animation:

```
//animated slideInDown - name of the animation
<div class="modal-content animated slideInDown">
    <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    <div id="header" class="headerClass"></div>
    <div id="myDiv" class="added">

    </div>
    <div id="buttons" class="buttonsClass"></div>

</div>
```

Where should I add the animation to close?

Comment: Conceptually, you want: `.popup.closed { animation-name: closingAnimation; } .popup.opened { animation-name: openingAnimation; }`. You should provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), though.

Comment: Could you please add some code in order to find a solution